# vue vuejs - vuesax sidebar component does not appear properly

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component, vuejs3, vuesax

is anyone can help me to with [this components?](https://vuesax.com/docs/components/Sidebar.html#open)

I've tried to create my own component but I can only see [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YMyjp.png):

- into my code:

  - I copied the code from the link into a component and called the component in my app.
  - I dropped this in the head:

  `<link href="https://unpkg.com/vuesax@4.0.1-alpha.16/dist/vuesax.min.css" rel="stylesheet">`

  - and dropped this in the body:

  `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>`

  `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuesax@4.0.1-alpha.16/dist/vuesax.min.js"></script>`

  `<script src="https://unpkg.com/vuesax"></script>`

Comment: anything new? it an UP comment

Comment: anything new? it an UP comment

Comment: someone will answer, give time to the community

Comment: I hope someone will haha